# how to use bootstrap's modal dialog only, instead of the whole bootstrap.css to aviod conflicting with my own css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, conflict

how to use bootstrap's modal dialog only,  instead of the whole bootstrap.css to aviod conflicting with my own css.

I know maybe using fancybox is a better solution, but I just want the  bootstrap's modal window's  style..

Comment: Just include your CSS after the bootstrap.css file. Whichever is last is what is used in CSS.

Comment: @Jack, thank you for reply , but it's impossible in my own css files to define every elements to overwrite those ones defined in bootstrap.css

Comment: Um, why would you need to do that? Wouldn't you have all your elements defined in your css? I assume you're resetting everything at the beginning of your CSS, if not, you should do that and it would be fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using \*just\* Bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088160/using-just-bootstrap-modal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include your CSS after the bootstrap.css file. Whichever is last is what is used in CSS.

If you're worried about element specific css rules like `input` or `div` etc, then just reset everything at the beginning of your css file.

Google CSS reset and found this:

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

From that you can simply customize a couple things like text/link colors and hovers, etc, but most of the css in bootstrap is used with classes so people can have custom css with it.

Answer (score 5):

here is the complete css only for the bootstrap modal.

```css
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}
a {
  background-color: transparent;
}
html {
  font-size: 10px;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
a {
  color: #337ab7;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #23527c;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
.close {
  float: right;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #000000;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.2;
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
button.close {
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.modal {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  outline: 0;
}
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -25%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -25%);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -25%);
  transform: translate(0, -25%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}
.modal.in .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.modal-open .modal {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.modal-dialog {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  margin: 10px;
}
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
          background-clip: padding-box;
  outline: 0;
}
.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  background-color: #000000;
}
.modal-backdrop.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
.modal-backdrop.in {
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
.modal-header {
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  min-height: 16.42857143px;
}
.modal-header .close {
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.modal-title {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
}
.modal-body {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
}
.modal-footer {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.modal-footer .btn + .btn {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.modal-footer .btn-group .btn + .btn {
  margin-left: -1px;
}
.modal-footer .btn-block + .btn-block {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.modal-scrollbar-measure {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.clickable {
  cursor:pointer;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 30px auto;
  }
  .modal-content {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  .modal-sm {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .modal-lg {
    width: 900px;
  }
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after,
.modal-footer:before,
.modal-footer:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after,
.modal-footer:after {
  clear: both;
}
.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.pull-right {
  float: right !important;
}
.pull-left {
  float: left !important;
}
.hide {
  display: none !important;
}
.show {
  display: block !important;
}
.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.text-hide {
  font: 0/0 a;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
}
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
.affix {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the css for bootstrap's modal:

```
.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  background-color: #000000;
}
.modal-backdrop.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}
.modal-backdrop,
.modal-backdrop.fade.in {
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1050;
  width: 560px;
  margin-left: -280px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  *border: 1px solid #999;
  /* IE6-7 */

  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  outline: none;
}
.modal.fade {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
  transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
  top: -25%;
}
.modal.fade.in {
  top: 10%;
}
.modal-header {
  padding: 9px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
.modal-header .close {
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.modal-header h3 {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.modal-body {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 400px;
  padding: 15px;
}
.modal-form {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.modal-footer {
  padding: 14px 15px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
  *zoom: 1;
}
.modal-footer:before,
.modal-footer:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  line-height: 0;
}
.modal-footer:after {
  clear: both;
}
.modal-footer .btn + .btn {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.modal-footer .btn-group .btn + .btn {
  margin-left: -1px;
}
.modal-footer .btn-block + .btn-block {
  margin-left: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .modal.fade {
    top: -100px;
  }
  .modal.fade.in {
    top: 20px;
  }
}
```

Just make sure you use bootstrap's modal classes and include the js too for it to work.

Comment: This isn't the complete CSS for the modal, as it produces a dialog box that doesn't display properly